# Why css is called cascading style sheet?

Tags: css

I'm just wondering to know that about cascading. Is the css called cascading because this stores in cache?

What is the reason for css to say or name it cascading?

Comment: "Is the css called cascading because this stores in cache?" Wha—? Sorry but that's just about the most bizarre statement I've read today. How are the two words even remotely related (other than the fact that they both start with "ca", which in itself doesn't make them so)?

Answer (score 3):

Cascading is when multiple items is row follow each other's in order

Have you ever heard about the Domino's cascading effect,  in which when a piece fall it will cause the next piece fall till the end.

Css is named cascading because the effect is cascading according to where is your style

There are 3 locations where the style is located

1. Inline
2. Internal
3. External

So the styling is cascading in following order:

The html element will search for inline style and apply it,  if there is no inline style then it will CASCADE to internal style and apply it, and if there is no internal style then it Will CASCADE to the external style and apply it

Got it?

Comment: what does "internal" and "external" mean? Styles declared in the same doc & styles linked externally?

Comment: yes , internal is written in the same html page.. external is linked code  ( inline is written within the html element)